# Woocoomerce Generate API Key button not responding at all

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, rest, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to generate a REST API Key to connect an app with my site but after many trials, I could not get able to generate key.
I tried different names, Read-Write-Read/Write…but every time the Generate API Key did not work. After clicking nothing happens. I have tried different browsers, Cleared Browser and WordPress Cache along with my cpanel cache, But nothing changed.
The Generate Key button is not responding at all.

I mean It is not even loading, nothing is happening.

I will add a link to a screen recoding for help.
[Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LPrS3SySJlQFkvyMR1EjBYfimlsWJF71/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: No one to answer???

Answer (score 0):

It's default woocomerce functionality. If REST API is not generating means there is an issue with any other plugin or js error.

so first deactivate all other plugins and try again if working, then again active other plugins one by one and try it to generate key, in this way, you can easily found which plugin has an issue.

Comment: Hello, Thank yuo for your response. I actually tried this way...I have also asked the same question on wordpress.org here is the link, maybe the convesation there along with screenshots would give you some lead???     https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rest-api-generate-key-not-responding/#post-14784257